# How to get full height of a SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I am a beginner and I am trying to convert a PSD to HTML. I want to get the full height of the background image inserted into the `.hero` class. How can I do that?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

.name-plate {
  text-align: center;
}

.name-plate h2 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.name-plate p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

header nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 127, 127, 0.5);
  padding: 1rem 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

header nav .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
}

header nav .container .logo img {
  width: 75%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header nav .container ul {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: row;
          flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
      -ms-flex-positive: 1;
          flex-grow: 1;
}

header nav .container ul li {
  margin-left: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

header nav .container ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

header nav .container .search i {
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

header .hero {
  background: url(https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1625910102/StackOverflow/header-image_drdrkx.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
}

header .hero .container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

header .hero .container .hero-text {
  width: 50%;
}

header .hero .container .hero-text h2 {
  font-size: 4.5rem;
  color: #fff;
}

header .hero .container .hero-text p {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 1rem 0 3rem;
}

header .hero .container .hero-text a {
  background: #fff;
  color: #ff7f7f;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0.8rem 3rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.best-seller {
  background-color: #ff7f7f;
  padding: 20rem 0 5rem;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
    <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/djz3p8sux/image/upload/v1625910096/StackOverflow/logo_mpa0mr.png" alt="Delicious-Sushi-Logo">
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Promo</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="search">
                    <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="hero">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="hero-text">
                    <h2>Delicious</h2>
                    <h2>Sushi</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia odio vitae vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Order now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="best-seller">
        <div class="name-plate">
            <h2>Best Seller</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus lacinia odio vitae vestibulum vestibulum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want it will be looks like the below image:

[image]

How can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your SVG file open it with text editor and you will height of svg. Change svg wrapper div height to the svg height.

Comment: Oh so sorry. According to your answer when I am going to edit the SVG file I saw that the image is not SVG file. This is a png file. So sorry for the mistake.